# Trying to install HGL, X11 error

Tags: linux, haskell, x11, cabal

I've been trying to install HGL (Haskell Graphics Library), I used command cabal install HGL-3.2.0.5. That's what I'm getting:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring X11-1.6.1.1...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking whether to build Xinerama... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking X11/extensions/Xinerama.h usability... no
checking X11/extensions/Xinerama.h presence... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xinerama.h... no
WARNING: Xinerama headers not found. Building without Xinerama support
checking X11/extensions/Xrandr.h usability... no
checking X11/extensions/Xrandr.h presence... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xrandr.h... no
configure: error: X11/extensions/Xrandr.h (from libXrandr) is required
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HGL-3.2.0.5 depends on X11-1.6.1.1 which failed to install.
X11-1.6.1.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I googled a lot, however it didn't help me enough. Could someone help me fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant bit of the error message is

```
  configure: error: X11/extensions/Xrandr.h (from libXrandr) is required
```

cabal does not install C dependencies, so you need to install libXrandr separately (e.g. through the package manager of your distro).

Comment: A clarification: X11-related headers are probably in the *development* version of the X11 package (the name normally ends with `-dev` or `-devel`).